# Rest API Performance issues while loading data from multiple lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

We are showing data in dashboard from multiple SharePoint lists using RestAPI Get calls and there are multiple nested ajax calls. Due to all those, page is taking approx 2 min. for loading. we want metadata of columns as well. So how i can improve the performance of this?

```
var siteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
function fetchDetails()
{


//fetchClientName();
     $.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Client%20System')/items?$top=20&$select=*&$orderby=Title asc",
            type: "GET",
           // contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                      },
                      beforeSend: function(){
    // Show image container
    $("#loading-image").show();
   },
            success: function(data) {


                //alert("Demographics added successfully");
                //console.log(data.d.Title);
               // console.log(data);
                 var tr=[]; 
                for( var i=0;i<data.d.results.length;i++)
                {


          var details =  fetchClientDetails(data.d.results[i].Id);
          var counts = fetchSystemProfileStatus(data.d.results[i].Id,details.tat);
          var spRoleDetails = fetchSystemProcessRole(data.d.results[i].Id);


                tr.push('<tr>');
                tr.push("<td><b> " + data.d.results[i].Title + "</b></td>");

                if(data.d.results[i].InfoComplete)
                {
                    if(data.d.results[i].InfoComplete == true)
                    {
                        tr.push("<td><input type='checkbox' value='true' checked disabled></td>");
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        tr.push("<td><input type='checkbox' value='false' disabled></td>");
                    }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    tr.push("<td><input type='checkbox' disabled></td>");
                 }

                //tr.push("<td> Contact Details: <br> Name :"+details.name +"<br> Email :"+details.email+ "<br> Phone :"+ details.phone +"<br> Process Roles: "+ProcessRoleCount+"  </td>");
                tr.push("<td>" +counts.countNew+   "</td>");
                tr.push("<td>" +counts.countOpen+   "</td>");

                if(counts.countDelayed > 0)
                {
                tr.push("<td style='background: gainsboro;'>" +counts.countDelayed+   "</td>");
                }
                else if (counts.countDelayed > 7)
                {
                tr.push("<td style='background: orangered;'>" +counts.countDelayed+   "</td>");
                }
                else
                {
                tr.push("<td>" +counts.countDelayed+   "</td>");
                }

                tr.push("<td>" + counts.countPV +  "</td>");
                tr.push("<td>" +counts.countV+   "</td>");
                tr.push("<td>" + counts.count + "</td>");
                tr.push("<td>" +spRoleDetails.EAC+   "</td>");
                tr.push('</tr>');
                if(data.d.results[i].AdditionalNotes)
                {
                    tr.push('<tr><td colspan="8" ><p class="show-read-more">'+data.d.results[i].AdditionalNotes+'</p></td> <td> </td></tr>');
                }
                else
                {
                  tr.push('<tr><td colspan="8" ><p class="show-read-more"> </p></td> <td> </td></tr>');
                }

                }
                $('tbody').append($(tr.join('')));

            },
             complete:function(data){
    // Hide image container
    $("#loading-image").hide();
    var maxLength = 100;
    $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
        var myStr = $(this).text();
        //alert(myStr);
        if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
            var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);

            var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
            //alert(removedStr);
            $(this).empty().html(newStr);
            $(this).append(' <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more">read more...</a>');
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">' + removedStr + '</span>');
            $(".more-text").hide();
        }
    });
    $(".read-more").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".more-text").contents().unwrap();
        $(this).remove();
    });


   },
            error: function(error) {

                   console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });


}

function fetchClientName()
{

     $.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Client%20Project')/items",
            type: "GET",
           // contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                      },
            success: function(data) {

                //alert("Demographics added successfully");
                //console.log(data);
                //console.log("client Project");
                //alert(data.d.results[0].Title);

                $("#clientName").text(data.d.results[0].Title);      


            },
            error: function(error) {

                   console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });

}

function fetchClientDetails(Id)
{
         var name="";
     var email="";
     var phone = 0;
     var tat = 0;
     $.ajax({
            //url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Client%20System')/items?$select=*,ClientContactEmail/EMail&$expand=ClientContactEmail",
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Client%20System')/items?$select=ID,ExpectedTurnaroundTime",
            type: "GET",
            //contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            async:false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                      },
            success: function(data) {

                for( var j=0;j<data.d.results.length;j++)
                {

                    if(data.d.results[j].ID== Id)
                    {
                        //name = data.d.results[j].ClientContactName;
                        //phone= data.d.results[j].ClientContactPhoneNumber;
                        //email= data.d.results[j].ClientContactEmail.EMail;
                        tat = data.d.results[j].ExpectedTurnaroundTime;
                    }
                }



            },
            error: function(error) {

                   console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });

    return {tat:tat};


}
function fetchSystemProfileStatus(Id,tat)
{
     var count = 0;
     var countPV = 0;
     var countV = 0;
     var countNew = 0;
     var countOpen = 0;
     var countDelayed = 0;
     $.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Agent%20SystemRole%20Map')/items?$top=2000&$select=*,AgentID/ID,AgentID/DateOffboarded,ClientSystemName/ID,ClientSystemName/Title&$expand=AgentID,ClientSystemName",
            type: "GET",
            //contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            async:false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                      },
            success: function(data) {

                 //console.log("Hello");
                //console.log(data);

                var today = new Date();


                 for( var j=0;j<data.d.results.length;j++)
                {
                    var  created = new Date(data.d.results[j].Created); 
                 //alert(created.getDate()); 
                var sum = new Date(data.d.results[j].Created);
                    sum.setDate(created.getDate() + parseInt(tat));
                    //alert("sum is "+sum);
                    var finalDate = new Date();
                    finalDate = sum < today;
                    //alert(tat +" created----  "+created +" sum----"+sum +"finalDate"+ finalDate);

                    //console.log(data.d.results[j].AgentID.DateOffboarded +"---"+data.d.results[j].AgentIDId+"-----"+data.d.results[j].AgentID.ID);
                    //var DateOff = fetchAgentDetails(data.d.results[j].AgentIDId);
                    /*if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.Title=="Enterprise Bill Viewer")
                    {
                    console.log(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.Title +"-------"+data.d.results[j].AccessStatus);
                    }*/

                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.ID== Id)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.ID== Id &&(data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'New'))
                    {
                        countNew++;
                    }

                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.ID== Id  &&(data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'Requested' || data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'ReRequest'))
                    {
                        countOpen++;
                    }
                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.ID== Id  && data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'Pending Verification')
                    {
                        countPV++;
                    }
                    //if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemRoleIDId== Id && !(data.d.results[j].AgentID.DateOffboarded) &&data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'Verified')
                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.ID== Id &&data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'Verified')

                    {
                        countV++;
                    }
                   /* if(data.d.results[j].AccessStatus != "New")
                    {
                    alert(data.d.results[j].AccessStatus +"--   id  --"+data.d.results[j].ClientSystemRoleIDId +"final"+ finalDate);
                    }*/
                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystemName.ID== Id && (data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'Requested' || data.d.results[j].AccessStatus == 'ReRequest') && finalDate)
                    {
                        countDelayed++; 
                    }


                }




            },
            error: function(error) {

                   console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });

  return {count:count,countNew:countNew,countOpen:countOpen,countDelayed:countDelayed,countPV:countPV,countV:countV};
}


function fetchSystemProcessRole(Id)
{
 var EAC = 0;
 var ProcessRoleCount = 0;
            $.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('SystemRole%20ProcessRole%20Map')/items?$top=1000&$select=*,BusinessProcessRole/BusinessProcessRole,ClientSystem/ID&$expand=BusinessProcessRole,ClientSystem",
            type: "GET",
            //contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            async:false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                      },
            success: function(data) {
                //  console.log("Hi");
                //console.log(data);

                 for( var j=0;j<data.d.results.length;j++)
                {
                    if(data.d.results[j].ClientSystem.ID== Id)
                    {
                        ProcessRoleCount++;

                        var pRole = data.d.results[j].BusinessProcessRole.BusinessProcessRole;
                     var tempEAC =  fetchProcessRole(pRole);
                        EAC = EAC + tempEAC;
                    }
                }
                //alert(EAC);

            },
            error: function(error) {

                   console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });

return {ProcessRoleCount:ProcessRoleCount,EAC:EAC};

}

function fetchProcessRole(pRole)
{
    var EAC = 0;
    $.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Business%20Process%20Role')/items?$select=BusinessProcessRole,ExpectedAgentCount",
            type: "GET",
            //contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            async:false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                      },
            success: function(data) {

                //alert("Demographics added successfully");
                //console.log(data);
                //console.log("client Project");
                //alert(data.d.results[0].Title);
                for( var j=0;j<data.d.results.length;j++)
                {
                    if(data.d.results[j].BusinessProcessRole==pRole)
                    {
                    EAC += data.d.results[j].ExpectedAgentCount;
                    }
                }


            },
            error: function(error) {

                   console.log(error);
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }

        });
return EAC;

}
```

you can see in the above ajax call success, we are calling 3 funtions which will run separate ajax calls and will loop through list items one by one and then return the values which we show in dashboard.

Comment: If these REST API calls are not dependent on each other then you can call these APIs in parallel using promise pattern.

Comment: Can you post examples of your code?  In addition to what Ganesh suggests, maybe we can help with how your queries are structured.

Comment: @DylanCristy i have updated the comments

Comment: Thanks @AdarshAwasthi, but I was hoping to see the AJAX calls themselves, perhaps there is a way to streamline/improve how the queries themselves are structured in order to get results from the server faster.

Comment: If possible, use SharePoint search API. It should return data faster but as you know the updates will be delayed.

Comment: @DylanCristy i have updated the code. Please assist